# Push list of numbers while incrementing

Tags: javascript

I have a "count" number and I want to push some objects into an array, but if the last number on the object is smaller than the "count" number, it should add an incrementation and add first element with a count increment.

Here's my code:

```
let count = 15;
let completeList = [];
let list = [
    {
    'li_count' : 1,
    'name' : '-name 1-'
  },
  {
    'li_count' : 3,
    'name' : '-name 2-'
  },
  {
    'li_count' : 6,
    'name' : '-name 3-'
  },
  {
    'li_count' : 10,
    'name' : '-name 4-'
  }
];

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if(list[i]['li_count'] <= count) {
      completeList.push(list[i]);
  }
};
```

This only adds the list until the `li_count` is 10, but since the "count" is 15, I would like for it to loop again and the `li_count` for 1 would be an 11, the `li_count` for 3 would be a 13, and the `li_count` for 6 would be a 16, etc This way, the response I want to get is:

```
list = [
    {
    'li_count' : 1,
    'name' : '-name 1-'
  },
  {
    'li_count' : 3,
    'name' : '-name 2-'
  },
  {
    'li_count' : 6,
    'name' : '-name 3-'
  },
  {
    'li_count' : 10,
    'name' : '-name 4-'
  },
  {
    'li_count' : 11,
    'name' : '-name 1-'
  },
  {
    'li_count' : 13,
    'name' : '-name 2-'
  }
  
];
```

It pushed until the 13 because the next one is 16 and that's bigger than the original count: 15.

I hope I didn't made this very confusing.

Comment: Is the 10 that you add a fixed number? Or is it 10 because the last item in the list has that li_count? Or is that coincidence?

Comment: @trincot No, the 10 is just because thats the last item in the list. It could be more or less than 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Assuming that the `li_count` property values are non-negative and are appearing in increasing order, you could wrap your loop with an outer loop that will increase the additional value (`add`) that needs to be added to the `li_count` values as you will iterate the list again:

```js
let count = 15;
let list = [{'li_count' : 1,'name' : '-name 1-'},{'li_count' : 3,'name' : '-name 2-'},{'li_count' : 6,'name' : '-name 3-'},{'li_count' : 10,'name' : '-name 4-'}];

let completeList = [];
let last = list[list.length-1].li_count;
for (let add = 0; add <= count; add += last) { 
    for (let li of list) {
        if (li.li_count + add > count) break;
        completeList.push({...li, li_count: li.li_count + add});
    }
}

console.log(completeList);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! this works as I wanted it to! :)